# MYSQL Query matching number of symbols

Tags: mysql

In magic the Gathering there are cards with mana symbols in their cost. 
I want to fetch all cards with {U}{U} in their mana cost that means any number before it OR any non {U} character after it will quality, but it cannot fetch any cards with more than TWO {U}{U} in their card cost.

---

```
CARD_NAME       | CARD_COST |
-----------------------------------
Avatar of Will  |    {6}{U}{U}
-------------------------
Aven Smokeweaver|    {2}{U}{U}
-----------------------------
Ayesha Tanaka   |    {W}{W}{U}{U} 
-------------------------------------
Azami           |    {2}{U}{U}{U}
```

My result would be :

```
Avatar of Will {6}{U}{U} -ok
Aven Smokeweaver {2}{U}{U} -ok
Ayesha Tanaka {W}{W}{U}{U} - ok
Azami  {2}{U}{U}{U} - exclude not ok
```

Is there a clever way to fetch these results?

```
Select CARD_NAME from Cards `WHERE (`CARD_COST` LIKE "%{U}{U}%")`
```

Comment: Would it be better to change your database structure such that you have one row per cost?

Comment: That's how it is currently each card is a row.

Comment: I mean, even if you manage to get a query that does what you want, it would be inefficient. Why not create a separate table for the costs?

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking was wondering if there is another way to do it.

Comment: For example, `CREATE TABLE Cards_Costs (CARD_NAME, COST_NAME, COST_COUNT);` where you can use `INSERT INTO Cards_Costs VALUES ("Avatar of Will", "{U}", 2)` The trouble is that you need to refactor original data if your database already has useful content.

Comment: Even if you're not a fan of normalizing out the costs, you really would be better off having a black_cost column, a green_cost column, etc with numbers 0-n in each column.  The format as given is a bit useless for analysis by SQL.  If you really want to, MySQL has some regex functionality and you could theoretically write a horrible regex to do what you want but its a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Create another table instead. Assuming your CARD_NAME is the primary key in `Cards`:

```
CREATE TABLE Cards_Costs (
    CARD_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    COST_NAME CHAR(1),
    COST_COUNT INT
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX namecost ON Cards_Costs (CARD_NAME, COST_NAME);
```

So then you can query the values directly.

If it is inconvenient to maintain a count, you can also create a row per cost count:

```
CREATE TABLE Cards_Costs (
    CARD_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    COST_NAME CHAR(1)
);
CREATE INDEX namecost ON Cards_Costs (CARD_NAME, COST_NAME);
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cards_Costs WHERE CARD_NAME=:s AND COST_NAME=:s
```